# Unable to resolve service for type xxx while attempting to activate yyy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core 2.1 project with Identity enabled, however after making certain changes to seed users I run into some issues.

The error I get when I click **Register as a new user** is

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'namespace.Website.Main.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.

In the Register.cshtml.cs class I see that IEmailSender is injected but I have made no alterations to this and cannot understand why this error is happening? Please help

### Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddHttpClient();

        services.AddHttpClient<IExceptionServiceClient, ExceptionServiceClient>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
}
```

### RolesConfig

```
public static class RolesConfig
{
    public static async Task InitialiseAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Report", "Search" };
        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            var roleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
        }
    }
}
```

### Register.cshtml.cs

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Where in your code is that Exception happening?

Comment: @steve, add your `RegisterModel` model code please!

Comment: Did you forget to register a service for IEmailSender ? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#implement-iemailsender

Comment: By the way, when you encounter an error like `Unable to resolve service for type  xyz while ...`, it usually means that you forget to register such a service.

Comment: @TanvirArjel that has been added now

Comment: @itminus i understand that but before I tampered with seeding the db the identity service was `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>;` And no IEmailSender was registered at that point but it still worked. Please shed some light on this

Comment: @steve When registering a new user，the ASP.NET Core need invoke the `IEmailSender` service to confirm the email addresss : `await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");` . To fix this issue, simply follow the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#implement-iemailsender to add a service : `services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();`

Comment: @steve Check my answer. It should solve your problem.

Comment: @itminus Thanks! This worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are using `IEmailSender` thorough constructor Dependency Injection in `RegisterModel` but you did not register the `IEmailSender` to ASP.NET Core DI container. So to register `IEmailSender`, add the following line to your `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmailSender,EmailSender>();
```

Now problem should go away.

Comment: thanks I tried this but I do not have an EmailSender class and the one recommended in the links above require so many prerequesities. I curious as to why IEmail sender worked before I started using roles? Before introducing roles I could register and manager accounts fine. What do you think?

Comment: Enail Sender requires if you want to send confirmation email after registration. If you don't need this that remove the IEmailSender from RegisterModel.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand asp.net core identity more. Thanks Tanvir!